# Showing custom UIView when row selected

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to know if it possible and how to implement following user action:

The user taps on a button that is shown as UIView on a tableView row. After tapping on the button, a UIView containing buttons should appear, like in the image below:

[image]

UPDATED QUESTION:

I have changed my requirements. The UIView should be shown after swipping the row from left to right.

I have included following code to my cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
//swipe left-right
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeftRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGestureLeftRight:)];
        [swipeLeftRight setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft )];
        [cell addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftRight];
        //end of swipe left-right
```

And I have added the handleGestureLeftRight method:

```
-(void)handleGestureLeftRight:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gec
{
    {

        CGPoint p = [gec locationInView:self.tableView];

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];


        if (gec.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {


            NSLog(@"GESTURE LEFT-->RIGHT DONE");


            CGRect newSize = CGRectMake(0.0f ,0.0f, 150.f, 50.0f);
            UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:newSize];
            newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];


            UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [button addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(aMethod:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            [button setTitle:@"Close" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
            [newView addSubview:button];
            [self.view addSubview:newView];


        }



    }
}
```

I hope it will work as desired, now I will need to add more buttons and to change all CGRectMake params, to fit all the buttons inside the UIView.

Now, that I have this done, I would ask you only this question:

How to setup the UIView coordinates to put it like the picture, that means just above the selected row?

Comment: So where is the problem ? You don't know how to detect tap, how to add subview to main view or how to position it ?

Comment: I am on it, I will put my code when I have a working UIView. Thank you.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski, I have updated my answer with my code proposal. Thank you.

Comment: @rmaddy, I have updated my answer with my code proposal. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 . You can get the position of the cell on screen with:

```
CGRect positionOnScreen = [tableView convertRect:self.frame toView:parentViewController.view];
```

where `self` is the UITableViewCell and `parentViewController` is the the UIViewController containing the table. You need to do this in your custom cell. Then you can pass this value to your parent UIViewController. Add your pop-up view to your UIViewController using:

```
[myPopUpView setFrame: CGRectMake(myPopUpView.Frame.Origin.x , positionOnScreen.origin.y - myTableCell.Frame.Size.Heigh - myCustomCell.Frame.Size.Height, myPopUpView.Frame.Size.Width, myPopUpView.Frame.Size.Width)];
myPopUpView.Alpha = 1;
```

I assumed you had already created the pop-up view in your .XIB with the Alpha property equals 0.

2 . You can 'close' the pop-up by hiding it with:

```
myPopUpView.Alpha = 0;
```

You can also use `addSubView:` and `removeFromSuperview` for adding/removing the pop-up view instead of creating it in the .XIB and using the Alpha property.